# file.getTotalSpace() returning twice of the actual value

Tags: java, android, file

So i have a rooted android 4.0.3 device. Whenever I install something to the 'sd card' which happens to actually be internal, it creates this /mnt/secure/asec partition as well. following is the partial output of df.

```
    /mnt/sdcard              1G    65M     1G   4096
    /mnt/secure/asec         1G    65M     1G   4096
```

Now, if I try to execute the following code.

```
    File f = new File("/mnt/sdcard");
    long div = (1024*1024);
    long d = f.getTotalSpace()/div;
            Log.i("Capacity",String.valueOf(d));
```

The value it is showing me is 2Gb. What is going on here? And why is android 4.0.3 creating a secure mount point for these apks install on the 'sd card' anyway? Isn't that a JellyBean only feature?

Answer (score 1):

> What is going on here?

Try using [`StatFs`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html) instead of `getTotalSpace()` and see if you get better results.

> And why is android 4.0.3 creating a secure mount point for these apks install on the 'sd card' anyway?

Because that has been part of install-to-SD in Android since the feature was introduced in API Level 8.

Comment: StatFs sf = new StatFs("/mnt/sdcard");

long div = 1024*1024;


long statcap = sf.getBlockCount()*sf.getBlockSize()/div;

This results in the exact same value as getTotalSpace();


Thanks for making me aware of the install-to-SD thing. Sorry about the formatting..

Comment: @user16357: Hmmm. I have no idea why you would be getting those values, and I do not see an issue on http://b.android.com that mentions these methods. If you get a chance, post a project that reproduces the issue somewhere, and I'll try running it on some stuff here.